# CSS3 Animation doesn't work in IE10

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zXTSp/1/) contains a CSS animation that works for me in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but not IE 10. It doesn't start the animation in IE10 - can't see anything wrong here?

```
    .x1 {
          left: 200px;
          top: -150px;

         -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
         -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
         -o-transform: scale(0.8);
         -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
          transform: scale(0.8);
         -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
          filter: alpha(opacity=80);
          opacity: 0.8;

         -webkit-animation: moveclouds 47s linear infinite;
         -moz-animation: moveclouds 47s linear infinite;
         -ms-animation: moveclouds 47s linear infinite;
         -o-animation: moveclouds 47s linear infinite;
          animation: moveclouds 47s linear infinite;
        }


      @keyframes "moveclouds" {
          0% {
              margin-left: 1000px;
             }
        100% {
             margin-left: -1000px;
             }
        }

      @-moz-keyframes moveclouds {
         0% {
             margin-left: 1000px;
            }
       100% {
             margin-left: -1000px;
            }
        }

      @-webkit-keyframes "moveclouds" {
         0% {
             margin-left: 1000px;
            }
       100% {
             margin-left: -1000px;
            }
        }

      @-ms-keyframes "moveclouds" {
         0% {
             margin-left: 1000px;
            }
       100% {
             margin-left: -1000px;
            }
        }

     @-o-keyframes "moveclouds" {
       0% {
           margin-left: 1000px;
          }
     100% {
           margin-left: -1000px;
          }
       }
```

Here's the JsFiddle Link http://jsfiddle.net/zXTSp/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Jsfiddle in IE10

http://jsfiddle.net/2V3Sx/

It should be  `@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {`

not  `@-webkit-keyframes "moveclouds" {`...a typo...:)

Hope this works